# set different @page rule size when it matches classname in printing

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to set different @page rule size when it matches the classname.
I tried to research but the answers I found are pseudo-classes which I think is not
the solution to my problem.

This is my css

```
@media print {
   @page {
      margin: 13.2mm 0mm 12.9mm;
   }
}
```

html file #1

```
<div class='classname-1'>
   some contents here..
</div>
```

html file #2

```
<div class='classname-2'>
   some contents here..
</div>
```

The solution I came up is but doesn't work when I tried to print. It only applies
the latest @page rule

```
@media print {
   .classname-1 { 
      @page {
         size: portrait;
         margin: 13.2mm 0mm 12.9mm;
      }
   }

   .classname-2 { 
      @page {
         size: landscape;
         margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I have found none upon searching for appropriate methods/techniques for this. So I tried to customize the style of elements when printing.